# Post from View to Controller works but gives an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form in my view which is calling an action in the controller.

My View:

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("MethodInController","Controller",FormMethod.Post))
    { 

        <label for="firstname">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="firstname" /> 
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    }
```

My Controller action:

```
        [HttpPost]       
        public ActionResult MethodInController(string firstname)
        {
            string test = (string)ViewData["sbnamespace"];
            return View();
        }
```

This works just fine. The only problem is that when I hit the submit button on my view, it tries to navigate to my controller like so: http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Controller/MethodInController and I land on the default error page for the azure website.

I just want to know if there is a way to post the data WITHOUT navigating to a different page.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because author does not show minimal understanding of the problem to be solved.

Comment: What's the name of your controller?

Comment: Do you really have a controller named `ControllerController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this, I suspect this is what's going on, the controller and view are folders inside your project to make it clearer

[image]

So its something like this, Inside one controller:

```
//when you navigate to this page
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

//when you submit on this page
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string firstname)
{
    string test = (string)ViewData["sbnamespace"];
    return View();
}
```

and inside Index page:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    <label for="firstname">Name:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="firstname" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
}
```